# Setting up Custom Background

Tags: css, custom-background

I’m currently working on a website for educational purposes.

I want all of my pages look like [this one](http://www.dadi.rtu.lv/par-institutu/). As the background on the sides are made from image but the background for content is grey.

I have 3 problems which i cant resolve :

First one is that I cant get grey background to my first page at all. Second one being that if there isnt enough content to fill the page [like here](http://www.dadi.rtu.lv/studiju-programmas/), i cant get the grey background till the footer. Same with sidebars i cant get background color under them.

I tried to solve this using css.

First I set up background to all my body element

`background-image:url('http://www.dadi.rtu.lv/image/tikls.svg');`

And then i tried to fill the grey background under the content like this

```
.entry-content {
background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
#sidebar-primary {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    }
.widget-area .widget {
background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.page article.page { background-color: #e6e6e6; }
```

Searching in google and stackoverflow i know that it should be resolved with using div tags around my content and giving it my background color. But I cant figure it out.

My pages are set up like this (except the first one) :

```
<div class="grey"><!--this is my new div tag-->
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div>
```

CSS for my new div tag:

```
.grey {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    display: block;
}
```

My goal is to get my new div tag from my navigation bar till footer with grey background. 
Im stucked with this for a while so all help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this css style to make your background cover the entire page:

```
body {
    background-image: url('IMAGE URL');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width:100%
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left
}
```

Now, style your content's background:

```
.grey {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px // You can also set as 100%
}
```

Not that you should either set a width for your elements, or float it to the left to be able to set it's background.

Comment: Thanks, this one worked out great. But do you have any ideas how to make that div tag go till it reaches footer ? Because now it has this space between content and footer. I would like to have it grey too. You can see it here (http://www.dadi.rtu.lv/studiju-programmas/) Here is my CSS for footer (https://pastebin.com/c0258vT5)

Comment: You want to remove the space between footer and DIV? You should remove margin-bottom from your from your DIV, and margin-top from your footer. Remember to remove these margins for every sub-element standing between these 2 too.

Comment: Maybe i'm not getting the message across. I want this page (http://www.dadi.rtu.lv/studiju-programmas/) look like this (https://i.imgsafe.org/271e1ddd05.png). I tried to add bottom:30px; to that div tag but it didnt do the job.

Comment: This is because your footer's position is set to `absolute`. It must be set to `relative` instead. Remember, if your content's height is less than the screen's height, it will not reach the bottom of the page unless you define a `height` or a `padding-bottom` for it.

Comment: Ok, i set my footer position to relative and then gave my div tag `height: calc(100vh - 30px);` But now i can't scroll down. And i have no idea why.

Comment: the link you provided scrolls fine for me. Maybe it's a problem with your cache.

Comment: Just checked it, its not cache problem. And yes previously provided link works fine, but other with more content such as this page (http://www.dadi.rtu.lv/personals/) doesnt scroll down.

Comment: You should set the height for your `body` element, not the `.grey` class.

Comment: Setting height for the body element worked out fine, but now im again at square one. If you look at this page (http://www.dadi.rtu.lv/studiju-programmas/) There is again this space between "grey" div and footer. Which i would like to get to look like this https://i.imgsafe.org/271e1ddd05.png. Is there something I fundamentally don't understand or missed ?